# Computer crashing after errors in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: crash, blue-screen-of-death

I have been using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm experiencing real weird crashes with my computer when getting errors with my code. This is weird, like, these crashes don't happen if I don't code.

Basically, after getting an error such as "Out of range exception" or things like these, my computer gets like a time before dying, it's so confusing, it can take some minutes before crashing or it can crash seconds after receiving the error. **I'm wondering if this is a RAM problem since I try to access to a memory region that is not declared or something like that.**

Blue screen crashes that I get are like, PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA, SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION and KERNEL SECURITY CHECK FAILURE

Comment: Do you have administrator rights on your local machine? A lot of .NET software from MS is much more reliable if you have admin rights vs. regular user. It can cause the issues you are seeing.

Comment: @Buddy Yes I do have admin rights

Comment: The old standby, have you tried uninstalling completely and reinstalling? If you've done a lot of installations or removals of other software this can cause issues. A reinstall of VS ensures everything is set up.

Comment: @Buddy I didn't, it may be the problem, but I don't have time by the moment to do it (since my internet connection is poor and also I don't have a SSD so while installing my disk would be at max and I will get lagged) so I think that will be an option if I don't find another one soon

Comment: Also, if I uninstall/reinstall will my projects keep in their folders or do I have to make a backup

Comment: Should be okay, but always have a backup regardless!

Comment: okay, gonna take it in count. ty so much

Comment: If you're running with the disk completely filled that might be an issue, too!

Comment: @Buddy yeah, sometimes my disk goes at 100% with no reason (like system process uses all of it capability) and i got a pretty decent computer (i5 8300h, gtx 1050, 8gb ram ddr4 etc [but its a laptop]), but it's and HDD and I think that's why it goes like that

Comment: So that would be priority one, getting some disk space freed up. Without enough disk space, you can't swap virtual memory, and huge applications like Visual Studio, especially running in debug mode, are going to have trouble.

Comment: but I don't mean disk storage, I mean the usage of disk, I still have like 600gb freed to use

Comment: @user2191247 Ok so after a night I reinstalled VS and still my computer still keept crashing... So idk